# Angular2 get css property

Tags: css, angular, properties

How can I get css properties from a ElementRef element?
I've tried to use `element.style` but all the properties are empty.
The Renderer class has `this.renderer.setElementStyle` method but there is no `this.renderer.getElementStyle` method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`elementRef` instance has a `nativeElement` property which is an element node itself and contains most of the properties one may need.
Another solution which is well supported by modern browsers is

```
window.getComputedStyle(elementRef.nativeElement)
```

Comment: Well most properties of Angular components are empty by default unless you set some. What property do you need?

Comment: I need the css properties that are set by css code. In my case I'm trying to find the display property but my question is more like a global question.

Comment: not the best solution I guess, but it works `window.getComputedStyle(elementRef.nativeElement)`

Comment: Thank you it works perfect! But I'm using this code in ngAfterViewChecked which is called a lot of times. Does `getComputedStyle` use a lot of memory? And can you please edit you post so I can accept it as answer?

Comment: Ok, edited. I can't give an answer on it's performance. This needs some research.

Comment: I dont think this is a safe way to call method on window. Should this be done using renderer?